# Unity terrain texture missing after upgrade from 5 to 2020

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-terrain

I upgraded from Unity 5.4 to Unity 2020 and after my project was imported the terrain for one of the scenes seems to be missing the texture (see image below).
Anyone have any suggestions for a fix?
I've also include my Terrain Settings screenshots (2 images to cover the scrolling).

In case this is helpful, the terrain was part of a Free Rocks asset release over 5 years ago.

[image: Missing Terrain Texture]

| [image: Terrain Settings, part 1] | [image: Terrain Settings part 2] |
| --- | --- |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and a work around -
The problem was that, for whatever reasons, Unity v2020 was unable to import the Terrain Layer for the scene, and when I viewed the Terrain Layer under Terrain settings, the layers appeared empty. I removed the missing/empty terrain layers and the added one of the comparable terrain layers that v2020 was able to import. Worked out, looks better now. Terrain settings are as attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Backup and then try to delete the Library folder inside your project so that Unity rebuilds your project.

Comment: thanks, that worked for a different, but related, problem - my project is about 18G so I'm hoping I don't have to do it again (took almost an hour for project to reimport last time) - I may end up trying it again if no other alternate solutions are proposed

Comment: just deleted Library directory....didn't fix the problem - thanks for the suggestion though - (the import was much faster this time, 15 to 20 min)